# Android Studio: Cannot resolve symbol AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-asynctask

Android studio is driving me crazy with this error message! Everything was working fine until my PC crashed and ever since Android Studio is throwing compiler errors for my AsyncTaskClass. It's almost as if the android.os.AsyncTask import doesn't do anything all of a sudden. I'm running the latest build tools (25.0.1) and compiling with the latest API (v25). What can I do to fix this and get my AsyncTask working again?[image]

*EDIT:* To give some background: I've cleaned and rebuilt a dozen times to no avail. I've also tried the solution [here](http://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2014/11/fixing-android-studio-cannot-resolve.html) but I already had the proper build/API set. Very confused.

Comment: What about manually adding : `import android.os.AsyncTask;` in import.

Comment: @SatanPandeya Tried, still broken.

Comment: Did you use Windows 10? Then the solution is to clean and rebuild your project. Try to check if your project don't have a nulled file because of the crash.

Comment: Yes i'm on windows 10. I've cleaned and rebuilt so much though and it hasn't changed the error, I don't know how to do it any differently.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך Just checked and it turns out that ALL of my "android.__" imports (even in my other classes) are showing up red/unused. The app still runs but my IDE is pretty much useless at this point.  What's the fix?

Comment: try checking your sdk. In android\sdk\tools try to run the `android` batch file. Check if your sdk is working.

Comment: Fixed it. The solution was within Android Studio: File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to open Android Studio and select **File** -> **Invalidate Caches/Restart**.